# Font size not applied to datagrid columnheader

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf datagrid in which I am adding all the columns and style through C#.

I have applied ColumnHeaderStyle as follows:

1. written setter as :

   `var fontSizeSetter = new Setter {Property = Control.FontSizeProperty, Value = Convert.ToDouble(font.Size)};`
2. Style as:

   ```
           var headerStyle = new Style();
           headerStyle.Setters.Add(fontSetter);
           headerStyle.Setters.Add(fontSizeSetter);
           headerStyle.Setters.Add(fontStyleSetter);
           headerStyle.Setters.Add(fontWeightSetter);
   ```
3. Applied it to my `Datagrid's` ColumnHeaderStyle as:

`view.DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle = headerStyle;`

Current problem:
now, when I set **FontFamily** & **FontStyle** it gets applied. but column Header **textsize** remains same. It does not get updated.
[image]

**Entire Method:**

```
private static void ConfigureFontsForDataGrid(Views.StatusMonitor view, StatusMonitorAgencyFontType font)
        {
            var fontfamily = new FontFamily(font.Font);
            var fontSetter = new Setter { Property = Control.FontFamilyProperty, Value = fontfamily };
            var fontSizeSetter = new Setter { Property = Control.FontSizeProperty, Value = Convert.ToDouble(font.Size) };
            var fontStyleSetter = new Setter { Property = Control.FontStyleProperty };
            var fontWeightSetter = new Setter { Property = Control.FontWeightProperty };

            // Defaults
            fontWeightSetter.Value = FontWeights.Regular;
            fontStyleSetter.Value = FontStyles.Normal;

            switch (font.Style)
            {
                case "Regular":
                    fontWeightSetter.Value = FontWeights.Regular;
                    fontStyleSetter.Value = FontStyles.Normal;
                    break;

                case "Bold Italic":
                    fontWeightSetter.Value = FontWeights.Bold;
                    fontStyleSetter.Value = FontStyles.Italic;
                    break;
            }

            //Configuring data grid cell font
            view.DataGrid.CellStyle.Setters.Add(fontSetter);
            view.DataGrid.CellStyle.Setters.Add(fontSizeSetter);
            view.DataGrid.CellStyle.Setters.Add(fontStyleSetter);
            view.DataGrid.CellStyle.Setters.Add(fontWeightSetter);

            //Configuring data grid column header font
            view.DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(fontSetter);
            view.DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(fontSizeSetter);
            view.DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(fontStyleSetter);
            view.DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(fontWeightSetter);
        }
```

Comment: main problem is I am not able to set Font Size/Height to Header Content here..

Comment: I haven't yet got any solution please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote following data template in my datagrid resources. It works.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                    <TextBlock.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}, Path=FontFamily}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}, Path=FontSize}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}, Path=FontStyle}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}, Path=FontWeight}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Resources>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this code to resize font of Column Header in Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: I need to do it in C# only. I can't use XAML as I dynamically get different fonts for each datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code.

```
        var headerStyle = new Style();
        Setter fontSetter = new Setter { Property = Control.FontFamilyProperty, Value = new FontFamily("Calibri") };
        headerStyle.Setters.Add(fontSetter);

        Setter fontSizeSetter = new Setter { Property = Control.FontSizeProperty, Value = Convert.ToDouble(20) };
        headerStyle.Setters.Add(fontSizeSetter);

        Setter fontStyleSetter = new Setter { Property = Control.FontStyleProperty, Value = FontStyles.Italic };
        headerStyle.Setters.Add(fontStyleSetter);

        Setter fontWeightSetter = new Setter { Property = Control.FontWeightProperty, Value = FontWeights.Bold };
        headerStyle.Setters.Add(fontWeightSetter);

        myGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle = headerStyle;
```

Comment: main problem is I am not able to set Font Size/Height to Header's Content here